# Is it enough to point the definitions given in the book for proving this relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm reading Allufi's *Algebra, CHAPTER 0*:

> Prove that if $\sim$ is a relation on a set $S$, then the
>   corresponding family $P_{\sim}$ is indeed a partition of $S$: That is,
>   it's elements are nonempty, disjoint and their union is $S$.

I can't understand how to provide a proof on this, I thought I could only provide the definitions given in the book:

> A relation on a set $S$ is simply a subset $R$ of the product $S \times S$. If $(a,b)\in R$ we say that $a$ and $b$ are related by $R$ and we write $a R b$.

And:

> A partition of $S$ is a family of disjoint, nonempty subsets of $S$
>   whose union is $S$.

If the relation is defined that way, I guess these definitions are the proof. Is there semething wrong? Is this the real proof or do I need to express it in a more formal way?

Also, I felt something wrong when answering the question: He asks me to prove something about a set $S$, but I kinda feel in a lack of warranty on the content of this set, it isn't specified anywhere, I mean, it could be an empty set, couldn't it? I also read somewhere that the author wants me to use the axiom of choice for this, does it have something to do with this *lack of warranty*?

Comment: What is the definition of $P_\sim$ (given in the text)?

Comment: Isn't $P_\sim$ an **equivalence** relation, maybe? There is a one to one correspondence between the set $R$ of equivalence relations on a set $S$ and the set $P$ of partitions of $S$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer, but here says: "the quotient of the set $S$, with respect to the equivalence relation $\sim$ if the set $S/ \sim := P_{\sim}$ of equivalence classes of elements of $S$ with respect to $\sim$.

Comment: Gustavo: I notice you haven't accepted any answers to your more recent questions; have you been unhappy with the answers? You can always edit a question, or comment below answers, if you'd like more clarification, or if the answers do not address some lurking doubt/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there’s an error in the statement of the problem: it should specify that $\sim$ is an *equivalence* relation on $S$, and it should specify that $S\ne\varnothing$.

Unfortunately, you’ve not even begun to provide a proof. A proof that $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ is a partition of $S$ is a convincing explanation of why the members of $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ are pairwise disjoint, non-empty subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. I’m going to do most of it.

You need to begin by understanding exactly what $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ is: $\mathscr{P}_\sim=\{[s]_\sim:s\in S\}$, where for each $s\in S$ the equivalence class $[s]_\sim$ of $s$ is defined to be $[s]_\sim=\{t\in S:t\sim s\}$. These equivalence classes $[s]_\sim$ are the members of $\mathscr{P}_\sim$; you’re to demonstrate that each of them is non-empty, that they are pairwise disjoint, and that their union is all of $S$.

The first and last of these are easy. Since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, it’s reflexive: $s\sim s$ for each $s\in S$. Thus, for each $s\in S$ we have $s\in[s]_\sim$, which clearly implies that $[s]_\sim\ne\varnothing$. It also ensures that the union of the sets $[s]_\sim$ is all of $S$. We have to work a little harder for the third.

Suppose that two of the members of $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ have non-empty intersection. Specifically, suppose that $s,t\in S$, and $[s]_\sim\cap[t]_\sim\ne\varnothing$. Then there is some $u\in[s]_\sim\cap[t]_\sim$. By the definition of equivalence class this means that $u\sim s$ and $u\sim t$. The relation $\sim$ is symmetric, so $s\sim u$. And $\sim$ is transitive, so $s\sim u$ and $u\sim t$ together imply that $s\sim t$ and hence that $s\in[t]_\sim$. Suppose that $v$ is any member of $[s]_\sim$; then $v\sim s$, and we already know that $s\sim t$, so $v\sim t$ (why?), and therefore $v\in[t]_\sim$. This shows that $[s]_\sim\subseteq[t]_\sim$. I’ll leave it to you to show that $[t]_\sim\subseteq[s]_\sim$ as well (HINT: $t\sim s$) and hence that $[s]_\sim=[t]_\sim$.

In other words, if two members of $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ have non-empty intersection, **they are actually the same set**, just with a different name. This means that if I pick to members of $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ that are actually different sets, they must be disjoint. In short, $\mathscr{P}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets. Put that together with what we showed in the fourth paragraph, and you’ve shown that $\mathscr{P}_\sim$ is a partition of $S$.

Note that I did not need to know anything about $S$ beyond the fact that it’s non-empty. (One doesn’t normally talk about a partition of a non-empty set.) And the axiom of choice doesn’t come into the argument.

Answer (score 3):

The actual exercise should say:

> Let $\sim$ be an **equivalence relation** on $S$, and let $P_\sim$ the collection of equivalence classes of $\sim$. Then $P_\sim$ is a partition of $S$.

If you look closely, the exercise is referred from the actual text and the text which refers to it seems to be implicitly suggesting that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. <strike>(I don't consider this good writing, but that what it seems to me.)</strike> As Martin points out in the comment below, this is actually corrected in the [errata](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html). The link is quite useful for future questions where it seems almost obvious that a typo occurred.

*I am using [this version to back up my answer](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf).*

Comment: There must be a reason the list of [errata](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html) is as short as it is. The exercise is actually corrected there.

Comment: @Martin: Will you flag this for plagiarism if I incorporate this into my answer? :-P

Comment: Sure thing! :-)

Comment: @Martin: Done and done. Also short errata lists can be a consequence of no one actually reading the book in-depth. :-)

Comment: Oh no! Proper attribution -> No flag >:-((